# Изменить значение в Request

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

Есть класс `TestRequest`, в котором метод `rules()`. Мне нужно в зависимости от условия изменить `email` в `user`. Изменить так, чтобы в контроллер уже пришёл изменённый `Request`. Вот пример данных, которые приходят.

[image]

Пробовал сделать вот так, но ничего не меняется и в контроллер приходят данные без изменений.

```
Request::replace(['user.email' => 'test2']);
```

При `merge` добавляются новые данные в `Request`, но старый `email` не меняется.

```
Request::merge(['user.email' => 'test2']);
```

Как можно изменить данные в `Request`? Если нужно ещё что-нибудь по коду, пишите. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так будет работать:

Middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
{
    $userData = $request->get('user');
    if (empty($userData['email'])) {
        $userData['email'] = $userData['secondary_email'];
        $request->merge([
            'user' => $userData,
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

То есть проблема в том, что установка вложенных свойств через user.email не работает.

Так же, хотел бы добавить, что не стоит изменять данные в запросе пользователя. Данные должны приходить в том виде в котором, отправлены, если логика работы вашего приложения требует модификации данных, то для этого есть различные решения, например DTO, билдеры и т д.

Или например можно просто сделать в классе FormRequest геттер:

```
public function getEmail(): string
{
    return $this->has('email') ? $this->get('email') : $this->get('secondary_email');
}
```

Comment: А Вы уверены, что это стоит делать? Подменять данные в request-е да еще и  в middleware, на мой взгляд, довольно сомнительная затея.

Comment: Уверен, что не стоит делать такого. Но вопрос был про так как сделать, а не зачем)

Comment: Да, всё верно. Вопрос был как сделать. Спасибо огромное.